# MySQL error #1130 local host cannot connect

Tags: mysql

I have checked ALL questions relating to this topic and attempted ALL presented solutions, and yet my problem still persists.

In summary: the SQLserver can be accessed via console,workbench,...,everything when skip-grant-tables is in my.ini

I've tried everything from recreating users, privileges, passwords, flushing and the like, in all possible combinations (127.0.0.1 as opposed to localhost etc, all manually considering skip-grant-tables prevents most of the automation). Great. Changes made.

The moment the server is run with skip-grant-tables commented/removed, the server instance can again no longer be accessed from ANYWHERE.

It will ONLY "work" with skip-grant-tables.

I've gone as far as copying the relevant files of an existing database and changing the ports/base directories etc. Aaaaaaaand... here i am.

What on earth am i missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you connecting from localhost or an external computer?

Comment: Attempts from both the computer hosting the service and external ones fail without skip-grant-tables